# Is it true that when a root of a 4th degree polynomial is natural, the radicals inside the formula are always rational?

Tags: quartics

Given the formula for the 4th degree polynomial, is it true that a root is a natural only when all the radicals inside the formula are rational numbers?

Edit1: The coeficients are whole numbers.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg

Comment: Strange things can happen with radicals. $6+4\sqrt2$ and $6-4\sqrt2$ are both irrational, but $\sqrt{6+4\sqrt2}+\sqrt{6-4\sqrt2}=4$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right. Your answer helped me solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if get this right. If i just write the radicals who generate imaginary numbers in exponential form using Euler's formula then they will easily cancel each other? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. We were talking about natural numbers and irrationals, not about real numbers and complex ones. The numbers $\sqrt{6\pm4\sqrt2}$ are both real, so I don't see any room for applying Euler.